# Swift: How to access a tab bar item by pressing a nav bar button

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a CustomTabBarController class and a CustomNavBarController class.

The tab bar has five tabs and works fine. The nav bar class adds three buttons (home/messages/profile) to the right side of my navigation bar. When I click the home button, the function below will be triggered.

**CustomNavBarController.swift** (only the tappedHome function)

```
func tappedHome(sender: UIButton) {
     // Go to home page (tab bar index 0)
}
```

This is my AppDelegate and CustomTabBar file.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    window?.rootViewController = CustomTabBarController()
    let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    tabBar.selectedIndex = 0
```

**CustomTabBarController.swift**

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self

    self.viewControllers = [createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("News", imageName: "icon_news", viewController: MainController()),
                            createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Games", imageName: "icon_games", viewController: GamesController()),
                            createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Students", imageName: "icon_students", viewController: StudentsController()),
                            createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Ranking", imageName: "icon_rank", viewController: StatsController()),
                            createDummyNavControllerWithTitle("Info", imageName: "icon_info", viewController: InfoController())]
}

func tabBarController(tabbarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

     self.title = viewController.title
}

// Shortcut function for the tab bar items
private func createDummyNavControllerWithTitle(title: String, imageName: String, viewController: UIViewController) -> UINavigationController {

    viewController.title = title

    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    navController.tabBarItem.title = title
    navController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: imageName)?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)

    return navController
}
}
```

How do I tell my function in CustomNavBarController.swift to load the first index of my tab bar when I click the home button?

PS: The reason why I want two ways to actually go back to the home page is because the tab bar won't be visible in every situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing the following code in your `tappedHome(_:)` method should do the trick:

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let tabBarController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```